# Como enviar datos en solicitud HTTP con PHP

Tags: php, http

Estimados agradecería su ayuda con el siguiente inconveniente.

Estoy integrando una API de envíos llamada wschilexpress, la cual me devuelve una tarifa de envío un paquete según sus dimensiones y procedencia. Según su documentación debo tener el siguiente script en PHP para poder realizar la solicitud a su API

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; require_once "vendor/pear/http_request2/HTTP/Request2.php";
$request = new Http_Request2('https://testservices.wschilexpress.com/rating/api/v1.0/rates/courier');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'KEY_USER'
);



$request->setHeader($headers);
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}
```

Al ejecutar el script recibo el siguiente mensaje por parte de la API

```
{"statusCode":90,"statusDescription":"El JSON de entrada no es válido","errors":["A non-empty request body is required."]}
```

Según la documentación este es el body en JSON que se debe enviar, el cual contiene los datos del paquete a cotizar, pero no se de que manera enviarlo mediante el script de PHP, adjunto el body

```
{
    "originCountyCode": "STGO",
    "destinationCountyCode": "PROV",
    "package": {
        "weight": "16",
        "height": "1",
        "width": "1",
        "length": "1"
    },
    "productType": 3,
    "contentType": 1,
    "declaredWorth": "2333",
    "deliveryTime": 0
}
```

Comment: Intenta agregando `$request->setBody('{ "originCountryCode": "STGO" ... }');`, pero con tu json completo.

Answer (score 0):

La documentación de [HTTP_Request2](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php) menciona el método `setBody()` para añadir un cuerpo a la petición, que no has usado.

Un `$request->setBody($variable_con_el_json);` debe solucionar ese problema.